# Unable to Connect with my Database offer-system.000webhostapp.com?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
import pymysql 
import pymysql.cursors 

connection = pymysql.connect(host='offer-system.000webhostapp.com',
                             port =21,
                             user='id5165068_team',
                             password = '123456', 
                             db = 'id5165068_offersystem',
                             charset='utf8',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
                             autocommit=True
             )
```

========================================================================

**display**:
 (OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'offer-system.000webhostapp.com' ([WinError 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network)"

Comment: If you need help with the question, you need to add more logs and show some code as in what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: make sure you have properly set up your mysql server. your site at http://offer-system.000webhostapp.com works well but the port 21 doesnt seem to accept connections

Comment: I changed the port from 21 to 3306 but displaying new error : OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'offer-system.000webhost.com' (timed out)")

Comment: It looks like your code is not propperrly indented

Answer (score 0):

Given the error

> A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network

it seems that the script isn't able to reach the mysql server.

The code itself seems to not be having issues, so I'd check:

1. Is MySQL actually running on port 21?  That port is usually reserved for FTP, though you can run whatever you want there if need be.  The usual default port for MySQL would be 3306.
2. Are there firewall rules between you and the server that are preventing the connection?  These could be outbound rules on your workstation, network rules between you and the MySQL server, or some firewall running on the actual MySQL server.  If it is running on port 21 instead of 3306, it's possible that an ACCEPT rule didn't get set properly?

Comment: I changed port 21 to 3306 but displaying new error :        
 OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'offer-system.000webhost.com' (timed out)")